# Fetching AWS SecretManager Secret as Integer Value per CDK

Tags: typescript, amazon-web-services, aws-cdk, aws-secrets-manager, infrastructure-as-code

I'm trying to fetch the Secret as integer Value (port number) per CDK in order to create another resource. Basically when I need a String value for String parameters everything is working fine, but when I try to parse the String to int in order to provide the number parameter it does not work anymore. The problem is that CDK generates a reference for these values and it cannot be casted to a number value.
The question is: is there any way to retrive the Secret Value as number?

Here some code snippets:

**SecretManager Object:**

```
const secret = secretsmanager.Secret.fromSecretAttributes(this, "SecretId", {
      secretCompleteArn: someValidSecretArn
    });
```

**Working fine:**

```
host: secret.secretValueFromJson('host').toString()
```

**Not working because the parameter needs to be a number value:**

```
port: secret.secretValueFromJson('port').toString()
```

**Not working because port is null (it is not!), basically the reference cannot be parsed:**

```
port: parseInt(secret.secretValueFromJson('port').toString())
```

**Not working, same as above:**

```
port: +secret.secretValueFromJson('port').toString()
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the CDK's `Token` class to cast the token to a number:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v1/docs/@aws-cdk_core.Token.html#static-aswbrnumbervalue

```ts
port: cdk.Token.asNumber(secret.secretValueFromJson('port'));
```

It will be resolved to the proper value at deploy time.

Comment: is it correct to assume that the secret value will be shown during build time (in codebuild log) or only shown after the actual stack deployment?

Comment: It will not be shown at all, it will be displayed as a token throughout the deployment and in the stack template.

Comment: got it, we have similar problem with OP, where we are trying to make our frontend build to consume a secret value that exists in a secret manager, when i do ```cdk ls``` and the codebuild log it shows ```${Token[TOKEN.1532]}``` and i updated the code to ```cdk.Token.as_string(my_variables.secret_value_from_json('my_variable'))``` but its still not consumed by the frontend, and stuck where do we debug from here, do you have any pointers where to go from here?

Comment: How are you using the token? Where are you passing it?

Comment: i made a post about it so you can see the codes https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76103340/consuming-secret-values-when-building-react-using-cdk