# Consuming Secret Values when building React using CDK

Tags: python, aws-cdk, aws-secrets-manager

I'm trying to consume secret values that already exist in Secret Manager when building my frontend react app using CDK and Python

```
secret_arn = f"arn:aws:secretsmanager:us-west-2:1234:secret:my_variables-123456"

my_variables = secretmanager.Secret.from_secret_complete_arn(
            self, 'my_variables ', my_variables)

value_i_want = cdk.Token.as_string(my_variables.secret_value_from_json('value_1'))

bundle = s3_deploy.Source.asset(
            path="file-explorer",
            bundling=BundlingOptions(
                image=DockerImage.from_registry(
                    image="public.ecr.aws/docker/library/node:19"
                ),
                environment={
                    "env_variable_1": value_i_want,
                },
                command=[
                    "sh",
                    "-c",
                    " && ".join(
                        [
                            "printenv",
                            "npm install --cache .npm",
                            "npm run prebuild",
                            "npm run build",
                            "cp -r /asset-input/build/* /asset-output/",
                        ]
                    ),
                ],
            ),
        )
```

When running cdk ls or the actual build log i only see `${Token[TOKEN.1534]}` and after the stack deployment is done i can see the value is not consumed

Comment: First of all, that's a partial ARN, not a full one (doesn't have the six-digit suffix at the end). "Asset" means that it takes the source from the local machine before deploying. You cannot consume this token locally, it will only be resolved after deployment.

Comment: @gshpychka i intentionally made the ARN to look like a dummy (and yes the one in my codebase has -******). To answer your second statement, it is still not resolved/consumed after the stack deployment

Comment: The asset is built before the deployment, so it will not be resolved for the local build.

Comment: let me repeat it again, after the code is build in codebuild project and its stack is deployed in cloudformation (which is not local build), the variable is still not consumed

Comment: Your `file-explorer` code is being bundled into a `.zip` file \*locally\*.  See the [S3 Bucket Deployment](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_s3_deployment.BucketDeployment.html) docs for details.  But `from_secret_complete_arn` does not retrieve the secret value locally.  There are alternatives, but @gshpychka is 100% right.

Comment: okay now i understand, i thought that ```s3 bucket deployment``` can still retrieve secrets with ```from_secret_complete_arn``` function previously. do you know what alternatives that if possible can i try with the least amount of code refactoring but still be able to achieve what i want? @fedonev

Answer (score 0):

Your `file-explorer` code is being bundled into a `.zip` file *locally*.<sup>1</sup>  But `from_secret_complete_arn` does not retrieve the secret value locally.  To solve this, you need to do the two things in the same context, either both locally or both cloud-side.

Retrieving the secret locally with an SDK call as part of your CDK code or pre-build script is [possible](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/v2/guide/best-practices.html#best-practices-apps-context), but ill-advised. You will expose the secret value in the local CDK artefacts.

The safer alternative is to bundle cloud-side.  A [CodeBuild](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_codebuild-readme.html) project, either free-standing or part of a [CodePipeline](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_codepipeline-readme.html), can directly access [environment variables](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codebuild/latest/APIReference/API_EnvironmentVariable.html) from Secrets Manager at run-time.

---

[1] A S3 Bucket Deployment construct bundles the code locally.  The CDK sends the bundled `.zip` artefact to the CDK deployment bucket at deploy-time.  A Lambda-backed Custom Resource then copies the `.zip` file from the CDK bucket to your destination bucket.  See the [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/python/aws_cdk.aws_s3_deployment/BucketDeployment.html) for details.

Comment: my file-explorer is actually a folder that comes from github repo that i check out. So, i have 5 stacks and the code above is one of the stack that builds and deploy the frontend, these 5 stacks are separated to 2 stages which are defined in pipeline.py which controls which stage goes first. inside that pipeline.py is where i check out 1. the cdk code repository and 2. the github repo i mentioned earlier. This being said, i thought retrieving the secret is still possible cause the build is not locally as in done in my computer but at codebuild project which is similar to what you linked no?

Comment: @JackRogers  OP does not mention a pipeline.  The answer is valid for the question as written.

Comment: i didnt mention the pipeline and other stacks because i thought it was unnecessary information, but i explained more to give context to my case

Comment: No, the build is still "local", as in "before the template is deployed". It would be different if your CDK code defined a CodeBuild project that used a secret.